# A bug in my program. a Recursive method that returns a -1 when I pass an certain int

Tags: java, recursion

my code doesn't work for all cases:

```
public class P2Payment{
    int computePay(int DaysWorked){ 
        int pay = 0;
        if(DaysWorked<=0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if(DaysWorked==1){
            return pay = 1;
        }
        else if (DaysWorked == 2){
            return pay = 2;
        }
        else { // daysWorked >= 3
            DaysWorked = DaysWorked-1;
            pay = 2 * computePay(DaysWorked);
            return pay;
        }
    }
    int computeSaving(int sum, int PDay, int NumofDays){    
        if(NumofDays == 1){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(PDay <= NumofDays){
            sum = sum+computePay(PDay);
            PDay++;
            int accumlateSum = computeSaving(sum, PDay ,NumofDays);
            return accumlateSum; 
        }
        return sum; 
    }
}
```

When I  pass  computeSaving(1,1,39), I get back a -1. It seem if i pass anything above 32+ for NumOfDays, I get back a -1. How do I  get  the answer I want?

The code does the following: your pay doubles every day. The recursive method computePay return pay in cents for a given day.
Also Method computeSaving start accumulating the amount of cents you earn each day.

Comment: else more then one statment it should be in braces

Comment: While that's true, this technically works like expected, since those statements will only execute when the other if conditions are not true

Comment: Can you add a bit of specification to explain exactly what you expect to be happening?

Comment: Are you using an IDE to write this? If so, you should make sure you turn on the automatic indentation. (In Eclipse, hit Ctrl-Shift-F to format the code.) It will make a huge difference: you won't miss things like this any more, because it'll unindent the lines you thought were part of the `else` clause but weren't, and it'll become immediately obvious.

Comment: Also, your //daysWorked >= 3 invariant on your else branch isn't true. What happens if daysWorked == 0, or daysWorked < 0? You need another if condition at least for the 0 case, and probably for the negative case just as a fail safe.

Comment: okay, I fix that bracers part but I still get the error of -1 when I pass 
computeSaving(1,1,39)

Comment: I would sure love a job where I make enough money in a month to overflow an integer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your failure is because `int` stores up to 2^31 -1.

You keep multiplying by 2 in `computePay` and that's why you get bad results once you input

> numOfDays >=32.

I suggest using [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) if you really need such large numbers (arbitrary precision).
Otherwise maybe consider `long` (up to 2^63-1).

Example:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class P2Payment {
  BigInteger computePay(int DaysWorked) {
    BigInteger pay;
    if (DaysWorked == 1) {
      return new BigInteger("1");
    }

    else {
      DaysWorked = DaysWorked - 1;
      pay = computePay(DaysWorked).multiply(new BigInteger("2"));
      return pay;
    }
  }

  BigInteger computeSaving(BigInteger sum, int PDay, int NumofDays) {
    if (NumofDays == 1) {
      return new BigInteger("1");
    } else if (PDay <= NumofDays) {
      sum = sum.add(computePay(PDay));
      PDay++;
      BigInteger accumlateSum = computeSaving(sum, PDay, NumofDays);
      return accumlateSum;
    }
    return sum;

  }

}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
{ 
      P2Payment p = new P2Payment();
      System.out.println(p.computeSaving(new BigInteger("1"),1,32));
} // end main
```

Result:

> 4294967296

Comment: is the syntax: 
type variable;
BigInteger computeSaving ?

Comment: ...but one might well imagine that this indicates another error in the code somewhere! Monthly salary payments do not typically require a `BigInteger` to store them. I think the bigger problem is that it's not completely clear what the code is supposed to calculate.

Comment: @chiastic-security Maybe their currency got super-inflated? :D Like a CEO with £100,000 salary per month would be paid 3300000000 dong.

Comment: Okay, reading the code took a while for me to process it. Let me change my code now

Comment: The code does the following:
your pay doubles every day. The recursive method computePay return  pay in cents for a given day.

Comment: @DavidHang Yes, that's why it overflows int. If you want it to be able to scale (within your computer's memory limits anyway) BigInteger is the way to go.

Comment: awesome thank you. You showed me how to use BigInteger class, implement, and test it.